# Android Studio and SDK issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I installed **Android Studio** a month ago and it worked successfully and I was using **windows 7(64bit)** Then I setup a new **windows 7 (32bit)** and I reinstalled the **JDK** and **Android Studio** and I even downloaded the latest version of **Android Studio** but it didn't work.

First, a message pop up to set **environment variables** which I did, then  I opened **Android Studio** again and another message appeared :

> **Could not find main class com/intellij/idea/main**
>   [image: click here to see the error]

I searched about that problem and found that the solution is to add **JAVA_HOME** with value

> **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101**

Then, I opened it again and it didn't work but no messages appeared. I tried to run the SDK but an error message appeared:

> **Failed to execute tools\android.bat**
>   [image: click here to see the error]

Comment: Open Command Prompt, type: `echo %ANDROID_HOME%` then `where java` and finally `echo %PATH%` and post the results please.

Comment: i don't have a variable called ANDROID_HOME so it gave me the same name , there are 2 paths for java C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe

Comment: and for Path . C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\Sy
stem32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microso
ft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn
\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin

Comment: Firstly also post results of `java -version`. And add environment variable `ANDROID_HOME`, set it to path of folder which contains "SDK Manager.exe". Then append `;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools` to the end of `Path` variable

Comment: java version : java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode, sharing)